# Call a function on fragment load

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a fragment with a table.
the value of this table comes from a list in the bean.
I need to fill the list when the fragment is loaded.

I was trying to do that as I saw here:
https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2386966
but I see that it's filling the list on load and then the constructor of the bean is called again,
so the list get a new instance and in fact its empty again.

Do you know why it happens?
Or is there any other way to fill a list in the bean when the fragment is loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of your bean.
I suggest trying the 'view scope' first.

Comment: i'm using view scope. 
also i was trying to work with this sample http://adfsampleapplications.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FragmentOnLoad.rar. 
I added 'private int test;' in SampleViewBean.
I added <af:outputText value="#{SampleViewBean.test}" id="ot2"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can have the default entry point to your taskflow be a method call that initialize a list in a pageflowscope managed bean. Then you should be able to refer to that list in all the pages in your flow.